# how to insert bulk records over 20000 into the db instead using the CURSOR?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Hi actually m trying to insert the bulk records into the DB.
Records are more than the 20000.
I have to insert the records into three tables since these records are corelated.
For example :

```
1. One sort of data into the Table 1.
 1.1 another sort of data into the Table 2.
   1.1.1 another sort of data into the Table 3.
```

we can consider the above statement as nested lenter code hereoop.
Currently m using the Cursor for above approach but it is taking v v v v long time.
waiting for ur valuable suggestion....

Comment: Could you please post the table definitions and at least one example record you want to insert?

Comment: @bijay:this may help you [bulk insert with Oracle](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bulk_insert.html)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want an `INSERT ALL` statement.  Something like

```
INSERT ALL
  WHEN (<<some condition>>) THEN 
    INTO table1( <<list of columns>> )
      VALUES( <<list of columns>> )
  WHEN (<<another condition>>) THEN
    INTO table2( <<list of columns>> )
      VALUES( <<list of columns>> )
  WHEN (<<third condition>>) THEN
    INTO table3( <<list of columns>> )
      VALUES( <<list of columns>> )
  SELECT <<list of columns>> 
    FROM <<source tables>>
   WHERE <<some predicates>>
```

The `SELECT` statement at the end would generally be whatever query you're using to populate the cursor.  The conditions would implement whatever logic you implement inside the loop to determine which table to insert the data into.

If you know that a row from the cursor will always be inserted into a single table, you could use an `INSERT FIRST` rather than an `INSERT ALL` (the rest of the syntax remains the same) so that Oracle can stop evaluating conditions once the first condition evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your answer.But i am trying to insert the record into the target table from the staging table. And it shoud go in Nested Loop.

Comment: @Bijay - You indicated initially that there were three target tables.  Are you stating now that there is only one target table?